# Why is this circuit a two-stage amplifier?

Tags: amplifier, cmos

I am studying the following circuit and my professor calls it a two-stage amplifier. However I don't understand why as I just see

- a NMOS differential pair: MN0 and MN1
- a PMOS active load (current mirror): MP0 and MP1
- the bias circuit current mirror: MN2 and MN3

Isn't this just a differential pair (one stage)? Where is the second stage (common source)?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but I, my (RFIC design) thesis advisor, and my former VLSI professor all call this structure a single-stage five-transistor op amp. You may want to check with your professor directly in their office hour; this could be a typo or they could have reasoning that isn't clear to us.

Comment: This is indeed a 5 transistor op amp (ota), there is only one stage.

Comment: And if the prof says it's a two stage amplifier, then **when you are in that class** it's a two stage amplifier, and maybe you should avoid more classes with that prof...

Comment: It is a differential stage with an active load. Search brings up many sites such as [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/advantages-of-the-actively-loaded-mosfet-differential-pair/).

Answer (score 3):

It is not called a two-stage amplifier in any common usage.

It is a single stage differential amplifier because there is a single node where voltage gain occurs -- at the drain of MN1. The signal there is the difference of the signals at the gate of MN1 (directly), and MN2 (via the PMOS current mirror)

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate the gain and the input impedance of the shown circuit - in particular for unsymmetric operation with Vin1=0 (or Vin2=0) - you can treat the whole device as a **common-drain-common gate combination**.

Hence, it is not wrong to say that the system acts as a two-stage amplifier.